# Can we use 230V AC 16amp extension lead for 100V AC 16amp output?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, ac

Query: I have an inverter which output 100V and max. Current rating of 15Amp i.e. 1.5kW output. I have some PCs with adapters which takes 100V-230V input and current req. for PC is significantly below limit. Now they are physically quite apart(5 metres approx.) I live in UK and see that we get some extension leads which are specified for 230V and 16amp input. They are generally used for connecting mains at campsite. Can I use them? What could be the issues? I am not worried about sockets type i.e. thier physical shapes.
Thanks

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the cable itself shouldn't work. The plugs should also work fine, but it is a bit weird to have plugs and outlets designed for one voltage being used for another voltage.  In some cases that could create some "gotcha" for an unsuspecting user if they plug something in to the wrong voltage.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use them?

As long as you don't exceed the rated voltage or current limits the cables themselves will be fine.

> What could be the issues?

A UK 16A campsite lead will be fitted with blue industrial plugs and sockets, in a style variously known as Commando, BS4343, CEE17, IEC 309 or [EN/IEC 60309-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309). This style is available in a range of connectors for various voltage ratings and are colour-coded (blue = 240V) and keyed to avoid plugging equipment with different voltage ratings together.

If you make up an adapter between your 100V inverter, possibly fitted with some type of Hubbell connector, and your 240V IEC 60309-2 leads then at some point in the future someone, possibly yourself, will connect your 100V supply to a load that needs 240V to work safely or connect a 240V supply to a 110V appliance.

You can get yellow IEC 60309-2 connectors intended for 110V use. (Note in the UK 110V industrial appliances are usually supplied with 55-(0)-55V rather than 0-110V supplies.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an extension wire rated for 230V 16A for a 100V 16A application. (Note that in the body of your question, you say 16A, but in the title, you say 13A).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I have corrected my title.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use it. When it comes to power, the first thing is the current rating. The second is the voltage rating. The current rating determines the thickness of the wire (the cupper part) and the voltage rating determines how well is the isolation (usually the PVC coating). So if you choose a cable with the same current rating and higher voltage, it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Well explained. Do you have reference which you could point to? That would be fab.

Comment: Cable selection depends on a lot of factors, but maybe this will help: http://engineering.electrical-equipment.org/electrical-distribution/selection-of-power-cables.html

Answer (score 0):

Possibly irrelevant bonus unsolicited advice: budget inverters typically output a ‘trapezoidal’ waveform which has a lower peak voltage than the sinusoidal wave you’d get from a mains supply or high-quality inverter.  Depending on your PC PSUs you may find that they struggle with a 100V trapezoidal supply, as it’s the bare minimum rated voltage.  If you know that the PCs are ok with the inverter then all is well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Good to know potential issues. I checked it's a sine wave Inverter.